# Separate projects with access rights on VSTS

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, azure-devops

I have a solution with 4 projects in it i.e. an ASP.NET MVC project and 3 other class libraries.

We use VSTS as our repository. I want to be able to set separate access rights for these projects on VSTS so that each team (backend devs and frontend devs) can only access the projects that they need.

Can I do that if these projects are in a single solution or do I need to have separate solutions for each project so that I can set access policies for them individually on VSTS?

Comment: Which version control are you using in VSTS? TFVC or Git?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the access permission to each project folder via following steps if you are using TFVC version control and with this you need only one solution:

1. Open your project from web portal.
2. Click "Manage Project" button.
3. Click "Version Control" tab.

In the "Version Control" tab, you can set the permission to every folder individually.

If you are using Git, you can create four repositories in the team project to place your project so that you can set the access policies individually. And you can use [Git Submodule](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) command to add 3 class libraries project to ASP.NET MVC project, remember checking "Checkout submodules" option in your build definition when you build it.